# compare two lists of txt files, match and split

Tags: python

First csv file contains the filenames of the video files and the second a list of files from a specific path with the extensions.
I want to compare those two lists and add the matching file extensions for the results from list2 in order stacked by the find result (line by line).
I always get a randomly ordered 83 matches out of the 183 there should be. And is there a limit?

[list of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmYnG.jpg)

```
# list of video filenames with extension
list1 = set(line.strip() for line in open('D://RTS//marko//lab//python//xml_parse//aveco2venice_playlist//data//export//06-tv1-filelist.txt', 'r', encoding="UTF8"))
# list of files from playlist
list2 = set(line.strip() for line in open('D://RTS//marko//lab//python//xml_parse//aveco2venice_playlist//data//export//05-tv1-matpath.txt', 'r', encoding="UTF8"))


def filename(name):
    return name.split('.')[0]

list2_fn = [filename(name) for name in list2]
found_fn = [name for name in list1 if filename(name) in list2_fn]

# print results
output_diff = open('D://RTS//marko//lab//python//xml_parse//aveco2venice_playlist//data//export//05-tv1-differente.txt', 'a', encoding="UTF8")
print(found_fn, file=output_diff)
```

Comment: Could you show an example from the format of both files?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are converting them to sets, sets are unordered and does not contain duplicates. Instead you could use a list.

Comment: You could use the textfile with file extensions, load it and split the file extension, like your doing in your code. Then you could load the file with filenames in to a list or similar. You can then see if the file name exists in both files. I think you not be casting to a set, instead try a list.

Comment: I posted a screenshot of lists.

Comment: Could you supple more information about the problem? What is not working? What is the expected result? What happens instead?

Comment: @FRINTSO
I need to read/list 05-tv1-matpath.csv, find same filenames from 06-tv1-filelist.csv and get extensions of 283 video files. Ordered by match order from 05-tv1-matpath.csv  ---
Files are here: https:// we.tl/t-x6Iy5e8BW1